# How can I return reference to element in array in this case?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, reference

Given arrays of pointers, if I want to write a function that move about all the array and check if exists element with specific key (for example) , and if yes, I want to return exactly `array[i]` so that I will can to initialize this ceil again after calling to this function, for example:

`func(array,size,key) = 3`    -->   `array[i_key]=3`  (it's a simple example, not of pointers like I writed above, for explain what I want).

But, can be case that key not exists in the array, and then I need to return null (at least, I think so). But I can not do it while I returns a reference.

Someone have idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Look here for the discussion about _optional references_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858034/stdoptional-specialization-for-reference-types. Generally, its recommended to use pointers in cases like yours.

Comment: Why not return the pointer? If that does not solve your problem, I suggest you give a real example.

Comment: @Beta It's not solve my problem because that exists cases such then I will need to change the ceil that this element exists there by other element (for example).

Comment: @AskMath Don't understand. What can you do with references that you wouldn't be able to do with pointers? You could provide some example.

Comment: If a reference does the job for you, a pointer will as well. References, if used as function arguments or return values, are nothing more than some kind of special pointer with different syntax and some limitations...

Comment: @DanielLangr You can't change the value in this ceil by other element if you want. You get just the element itself.

Comment: @AskMath What do you mean by _"changing the value in this ceil by other element"_? Please explain.

Comment: I am sorry, I now understand your mention. I aksed for array of pointers, and I thought you mentioned about a some pointer in this array.  But now I think that your mention is to do something like that: `return &array[i]` , Yes?

Comment: Just one second: Given `C* c = array[i];` with some valid class C, do you mean you want to modify some unrelated `array[j]` via the pointer `c`??? You could, just add some offset to `c`: `(c + 10)->member = 12;`. However, this is ***highly*** dangerous! You need to know from pointer `c` the exact distances to to array begin and end to do such stuff safely! So if I met your point, I strongly recommend considering another approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, pointers is the way to go.

If you find the element, return a pointer pointing to that element.

Else, return a null pointer.

It's very common, and natural.

Comment: If you need to change the element that you found @AskMath, you could that via the pointer. Is that your question?