# Use of std::optional to pass a std::vector<int> to a functional by reference

Tags: c++, std, c++17, stdoptional

I am unclear if the correct code to pass an optional vector of ints to a function by reference is :

```
void test_func(std::optional<std::vector<int>&> vec)
```

or

```
void test_func(std::optional<std::vector<int>>& vec)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The second one.

Comment: What Is the use case here?  If the vector doesn't need to be modified then you could pass by const reference and use a default parameter.

Comment: That is the way I did have it in my code, but I found this new functionality and it will just make the function a tiny bit more efficient. Basically the vector of ints are indices and an absence of argument equals pick all indices.

Comment: Consider two overloaded functions, one that takes no parameters, and one that takes the vector by reference. Sometimes, the least complicated solution is often the cleanest one.

Comment: Since you cannot have optional references, there shouldn't be any lack of clarity.

Comment: This is bad usage of optional make your code unreadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm aware, this isn't possible in the standard as one hasn't agreed upon the effects of an assignment.

What you want to achieve is possible with a library feature:

```
  void test_func(std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>> vec)
```

Answer (score 6):

A non-owning pointer is a nullable reference type.

```
void test_func(std::vector<int>* vec)
```

Comment: Amazing how this simple fact is often forgotten

Comment: I think I understand what you are getting at, but would love an example on how to pass null?

Comment: @TonyGutierrez Type `nullptr`?

Answer (score 5):

Optional of references is [not part of the standard library at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858034/stdoptional-specialization-for-reference-types).

Both in principle make sense.

```
void test_func(std::optional<std::vector<int>&> vec)
```

Here the `std::optional` is passed by value (copied), and so is the reference inside it. Copying a reference means it still points to the old object. This might create unexpected behavior, as there are two instances of `std::optional` pointing at the same `std::vector`.

```
void test_func(std::optional<std::vector<int>>& vec)
```

Here the `std::optional` is passed by reference. You are accessing the same optional that was passed, no copying takes place.

The **second** one is more intuitive imho and available in STL at the moment, so it's **preferable**.

Comment: Thanks. Actually neither do quite what I hoped to do / are problematic. I wanted to pass an optional vector of ints, but ideally I don't want to be copying them. I am trying to add some new flexibility to some legacy code, which was hoping to do so with  minimum alterations via an optional parameter.