# Function with single optional parameter and default value in template function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++14

I want a function with has only 1 argument which is optional with generic type and has assigned `boost::none` as default value. Is that possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <typename T>
void f(boost::optional<T> v = boost::none)
{
    if (v)
    {
        std::cout<<"v has value: " << v.get();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"v has no value!";
    }
}

int main()
{
   f(12);
   f("string");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Overload is an alternative: `void f() { std::cout<<"v has no value!"; }`.

Comment: Lol @Jarod42 Apparently I have [too much time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236368/85371)

Comment: @sehe: And I forget: `void f(std::nullopt_t) { std::cout << "no value\n";}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm the other answer is *close*. But not quite there. `f(12)` doesn't "try to instantiate `f<int&&>`". In fact, it fails to deduce T because T is in [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context).

Also, your question was beside the point: even without a default value you have the same problem: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dzsfarvfP)

```
template <typename T> void f(boost::optional<T> v) {
    if (v) {
        std::cout<<"value: " << v.get() << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout<<"no value\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
   f(12);
   f("string");
}
```

---

Now, before I blindly show you how you can fix all that, ask yourself the question: *What are we doing here*.

If you want default arguments, doesn't that by definition mean that they aren't optional values? Maybe you simply need: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nKqfxhv5Y)

```
template <typename T> void f(T const& v) {
    std::cout << "value: " << v << "\n";
}
void f() {
    std::cout << "no value\n";
}

int main()
{
   f(12);
   f("string");
   f();
}
```

Printing

```
value: 12
value: string
no value
```

With some hackery you can combine the overloads by defaulting the template type argument:

```
template <typename T = struct not_given*> void f(T const& v = {}) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, not_given*>) {
        std::cout << "no argument\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "value: " << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints **[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8Ea56KKrW)**

```
value: 12
value: string
no argument
```

### What If You Require `optional<>`

In that case, in you specific example you would probably want `optional<T const&>` to avoid needlessly copying all the arguments; but see [std::optional specialization for reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858034/stdoptional-specialization-for-reference-types/26862721#26862721).

#### If You Really Really Want¹

Say, you MUST have the semantics you were looking for. You *do not care* that you won't be able to know the difference between calling with no argument vs. calling with an uninitialized optional (`none`). This is kinda like many scripting languages, right?

Now you have to make the template argument become *deduced context*, and then want to ensure that... it is an `optional<T>`:

```
template <typename T, typename = void> struct is_optional : std::false_type { };
template <typename T> struct is_optional<boost::optional<T>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T = boost::optional<void*> >
std::enable_if_t<is_optional<T>::value> f(T const& v = {}) {
    if (v) {
        std::cout << "value: " << *v << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "no value\n";
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<not is_optional<T>::value> f(T const& v) {
    return f(boost::make_optional(v));
}

int main()
{
   f(12);
   f("string");
   f();
}
```

One "advantage" is that that now you clearly see the copying being done.

Another "advantage" is that now you can support `std::optional` the same way: https://godbolt.org/z/1Mhja83Wo

```
template <typename T> struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type { };
```

### Summary

I hope this answer gets the point across that C++ is **not a dynamically typed language**. This implies that the idea of optional arguments of "unknown" type is really not idiomatic. (It might be a bit unfortunate that Boost called it `boost::none` instead of e.g. `std::nullopt`, perhaps giving people associations with Python's `None`.)

Instead, you can use [static polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783266/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-polymorphism-in-java#:%7E:text=Polymorphism%20refers%20to%20the%20ability,requred%20to%20happens%20static%20polymorphism.). The simplest version of that was the first I showed, using function overloading.

If you were to mimic a dynamic type interface in C++, you would probably use `std::variant` or `std::any` instead. To restrict the bound types you would use concepts (this is getting a bit deep, but see e.g. Boost Type Erasure).

---

¹ *i really really really wanna zig a zig ah*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible, but it doesn't work together with template deduction (`f(12)` will try to instantiate a `f<int&&>`, which doesn't exist). Your code will compile when you call it like that:

```
f(boost::optional<int>{12});
```

or explicitly instantiate it:

```
f<int>(12);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this leads to better code or even got to the heart of the problem. I [added some thoughts of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236368/85371)