# optional refence to an object: best way?

Tags: c++, reference, stdoptional

I want a function to return an optional reference to an object. Idea is to avoid copy, but seems like i should not be using according to this discussion:
[std::optional specialization for reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858034/stdoptional-specialization-for-reference-types)

Lets say I have a map of objects, and I want my function to return a reference to an object, if it is exists in the map. What is the best way?

```
struct HeavyObj;
std::map<int, HeavyObj> my_map;

std::optional<HeavyObj&> get_obj(int key){   
    if(auto it = my_map.find(key); it != my_map.end()){
        return std::optional<HeavyObj&>{ ? };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
```

ps: needed for C++17

update, If I use a pointer, I get:

````
#include <optional>
#include <map>
struct HeavyObj{
    int data;
};
static std::map<int, HeavyObj> my_map;

std::optional<HeavyObj*> get_obj(int key){   
    if(auto it = my_map.find(key); it != my_map.end()){
        return std::optional<HeavyObj*>{&(*it)};
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

int main(){
    auto test  = get_obj(3);
    return 0;
}

// gcc -std=c++17 -Wall optional.cc -lstdc++
optional.cc: In function ‘std::optional<HeavyObj*> get_obj(int)’:
optional.cc:13:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::optional<HeavyObj*>::optional(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   13 |         return std::optional<HeavyObj*>{&(*it)};
      |                                               ^
    ```
````

Comment: `HeavyObj*` or `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<HeavyObj>>`

Comment: Please add that to your question - it's too dense to read in a comment.  And returning a `HeavyObj *` would be my personal choice.

Comment: If you're going to return a pointer there's no need to wrap it in an optional. `nullptr` means it wasn't found and anything else means it was.

Comment: For your pointer code, what corresponds to `HeavyObj` is `it->second` not `*it`.

Comment: "optional reference" is called a "pointer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use the fact that an uninitialized pointer is `nullptr` to mimic the `optional` behavior.

However, some people might consider it cleaner to use `optional` anyway as it is more consistent if you have a similar function returning an `optional` `int` for instance.

You can use the `std::nullopt` when the value is not found and simply return the value if it is found (the compiler will do the cast from HeavyObject* to optional<HeavyObject*> but you can do it manually).

Comment: `std::optional<T*`> in this case is an example of bad interface. Logically, there are two kinds of return values - a pointer to a found object and some value that corresponds to a missing object. `std::optional<T*>` holds three states (empty optional, null pointer, and non-null pointer), not two. So it's not a cleaner return type, it's just a wrong one.

Comment: I would agree with you and wouldn't use it that way. But purists might say that a pointer should always be initialized. In any case, I think it's important to show how to use optional but I think your point is important too as in practice it's simply wasting ressources.

Comment: "an uninitialized pointer is `nullptr`" No, it isn't, it is an uninitialized pointer with an indeterminate value. `int *p;` could point anywhere. `int *p = nullptr;` is initialized to `nullptr`.

Comment: *purists might say that a pointer should always be initialized* - `nullptr` is the purest initialization of a pointer. ;) Pointers can be null by their very idea.

Answer (score 0):

Return a `HeavyObj*`, it is the idiomatic solution. The C++ standard library returns pointers that act as optional references in numerous places. For example:

- `std::get_if(std::variant)`
- `std::any_cast<T*>(std::any*)`

These are both C++17 functions, so they're by no means some outdated design from the 90s.
In your case, we can use raw pointers as follows:

```cpp
HeavyObj* get_obj(int key){   
    if(auto it = my_map.find(key); it != my_map.end()){
        return std::addressof(*it);
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

*Note: we are using `std::addressof` in case `HeavyObj` has an overloaded address-of operator.*

### Issues with `std::optional`

`std::optional<HeavyObj*>` would be a bit problematic, because it is optional in two ways:

- the `std::optional` may hold no value, or
- the `HeavyObj*` inside may be a `nullptr`

You only want one layer of optionality, so use `HeavyObj*`.

If you *desperately* wanted to avoid raw pointers, then the solution would be:

```cpp
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<HeavyObj>> get_obj(int key){   
    if(auto it = my_map.find(key); it != my_map.end()){
        return std::ref(*it);
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

However, this is not very ergonomic, because the return type is incredibly long.