# Default argument for 'bool&' in function declaration

Tags: c++, function-declaration

If I have a function declaration as follows:

```
int Remove(Object *spl, Object1* parent,
           int num, Object2* th = NULL, bool& proceed
          );
```

I get an error that I need to declare 'proceed' becasue 'th' has a default argument. I understand why. But how do I make a default argument for a "bool&" in function declaration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816293/passing-optional-parameter-by-reference-in-c

Comment: Swap the order. Put the defaults to the end of the signature

Comment: You can't have boolean references.

Comment: @Poriferous - sure you can.

Comment: @Poriferous I think you are confusing `bool` objects with bit-fields. You cannot have references to bit-fields, but a `bool` is at least as big as a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

All function in C++ have to end with the default arguments. It is *not* possible to call your function like so:

```
Remove(someSpl, someParent, 10, /* no argument, use default */, someBool);
```

Since you cannot omit arguments in the middle, they have to wander to the end.

Regarding the first comment clarifying the question, let me give a small example that should transfer fine to your application:

```
void changingBoolFunction(bool& someBool)
{
    someBool = false;
}

bool changeableBool = true;
changingBoolFunction(someBool);
cout << (changeableBool ? "true" : "false"); // output: false
```

Comment: I understand that. Let me rephrase my question. How do I initialise 'bool&' in: int Remove(Object *spl, Object1* parent, bool& proceed, int num = 0, Object2* th = NULL
          );

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: that value for `th` is a **default argument**, not an initialization. And once you've put in a default argument every argument after that one has to have a default. It's unusual to have a default value for an argument that's passed by (modifiable) reference, but if that's what you really want, you have to provide a `bool` object for that default argument:

```
bool bool_value = true;
int Remove(Object *spl, Object1* parent,
           int num, Object2* th = NULL, bool& proceed = bool_value
          );
```

After the function returns, if it changed the value of `proceed` that change will show up in `bool_value`.