# Can optional references be created in the new C++11?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

Given the new C++11 standard and the move semantics introduced in it, could it be possible to create default values for constructor references? Here [Default value to a parameter while passing by reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c) it is said that no, but perhaps the new standard allows some trickiness.

Basically what I want is to use a default object for the normal usage and to pass a mock object that records all the calls the host object has done in the testing phase. It should be something like

```
class A {
   B& b;
   public:
       A(B & b = B()){} // This does not work
}
```

and when testing what I want is

```
BMock bMock;
A a(bMock);
bMock.getStatistics();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about adding a `private: static B default_B;` so you can say `A(B & b = default_b)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, but since the reference is modifyable, as soon as you modify it, `default_b` won't be so default for other instances of A.

Comment: @UncleBens: Then name it `maybe_not_so_default_b`. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
class Foo
{
  B default_B;

public:

  std::reference_wrapper<B> b;

  Foo() : b(std::ref(default_B)) { }

  Foo(B & br) b(std::ref(br)) { }
};
```

---

Here's an alternative idea that might be lighter-weight, at the expense of dynamic allocation in the default case:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
  std::unique_ptr<B> pB;

public:

  std::reference_wrapper<B> b;

  Foo() : pb(new B), b(std::ref(*pb)) { }

  Foo(B & br) pb(), b(std::ref(br)) { }
};
```

Comment: +1… this answers the question he asked, not the one I originally assumed he was asking. The default object should possibly be `static`, though. And I don't know if the `reference_wrapper` is really better than a pointer here.

Comment: I think this solution is closer and I think it solves perfectly my problem. But just out of curiosity, how would you solve the problem that when I'm using the second constructor, the object default_B es wasted on each Foo instance? And the static solution won't be applicable as was pointed by UncleBen

Comment: @ancechu: If you insist on having one default object *per instance*, then you'll somehow have to live with the fact that there's a default object somewhere. Maybe it can be pimpled out, let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default initializer expression is a temporary object, and it will bind to an rvalue reference. However, you need to pass non-temporary objects through `std::move` to get *them* to bind to the reference.

Usually passing something through `std::move` indicates that it will be destroyed by the called function. The standard goes so far as to call the result of `std::move` an "expiring value;" although there's no real semantic necessity for it to expire, it's a pretty strong convention.

So, you can do this, but be careful.

Looking closer at your example, you want to keep a reference to `b` inside `a`, which means that there's nowhere to permanently store the proposed default value if no argument were used. You would be retaining a reference to a destroyed temporary. So unfortunately I can't really adapt your example…

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, what about this:

```
class A 
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> m_b;

public:
    A() : m_b(new B) {}
    A(B& b) : m_b(&b, [](B*){}) {}
};
```

On another note, I'm against storing off anything you take as a reference, I don't feel it connotes your usage at all. I'm also against members which are references, as they disallow assignment operators.