# function with parameter initialize

Tags: c++, function

My question is based on effect of the sentence `void print(const string& msg = "")`,
What difference if compared with `void print(const string& msg)`,

When i use the print function in `main()`, could I call the function without passing a parameter for function `print()`? like `p.print()`?

```
class Point {
      int i, j, k;
    public:
      Point(): i(0), j(0), k(0) {}
      Point(int ii, int jj, int kk)
        : i(ii), j(jj), k(kk) {}
      void print(const string& msg = "") const {
        if(msg.size() != 0) cout << msg << endl;
        cout << "i = " << i << ", "
             << "j = " << j << ", "
             << "k = " << k << endl;
      }
    };

    int main() {
      Point p, q(1,2,3);
      p.print("value of p");
      q.print("value of q");
    } ///:~
```

Comment: Please use preview to check your code formatting before you post the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, that's a default parameter. If you don't supply one, an empty string will be used.

So, calling `p.print()` would be equivalent to calling `p.print("")`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. it is known as a default value for a parameter. So, calling `p.print()` is the same as calling p.print("").

[Default value to a parameter while passing by reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c) is also relevant reading for you.

Comment: @Luchian: You are right. I edited my answer accordingly. That was before correct formatting of the question when one couldn't really understand what's inside print.