# Can returning a local variable by value in C++11/14 result in the return value being constructed by rvalue when no copy/move is involved?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I know that in the following situation that the compiler is free to move-construct the return value from `makeA` (but is also free to elide the copy or move altogether):

```
struct A
{
    A(A&);
    A(A&&);
};

A makeA()
{
    A localA;
    return localA;
}
```

What I wonder is whether the compiler is allowed to construct an object of type `A` from a local object of type `B` by rvalue reference if it is being constructed in the return statement. In other words, in the following example, is the compiler allowed to select `A`'s constructor 4 for the return value?

```
struct B { };
struct A {
    A(A&);  // (1)
    A(A&&); // (2)
    A(B&);  // (3)
    A(B&&); // (4)
};

A makeA()
{
    B localB;
    return localB;
}
```

I ask this because it would seem to me that the same logic that allows a local object of type `A` to be treated as an rvalue in the return statement should also allow a local of any type to be treated as an rvalue, but I cannot find any examples or questions of this nature.

Comment: Quick test on clang and g++ shows that both call #3.

Comment: `localB` is not an rvalue, so no (well, it can do whatever it wants as long as it follows the "as-if" rule, but it is unlikely to use a move here.) You would need `std::move(localB)`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not convinced that this is a duplicate - if you `return localA;` and prevent RVO, you'd select the constructor taking an `A&&`. The question is specific to the return statement.

Comment: @T.C. I don't think so. The "try rvalue first" trick is only allowed in situations "When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
object is a function parameter" (C++11 12.8/32)

Comment: I think Jonathan Wakely's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17483612/1708801) applies, although it is not really a duplicate per se.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The rule for this situation changed between 2011 and 2014. The compiler should now treat `localB` as an rvalue.

The applicable rule for `return` statements is found in §12.8 [class.copy]/p32, which reads in C++14 (quoting N3936, emphasis mine):

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but
>   not for an *exception-declaration*, and the object to be copied is
>   designated by an lvalue, or **when the expression in a return
>   statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an
>   object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression***, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an
>   rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed,
>   or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is
>   not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified),
>   overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an
>   lvalue.

The bolded clause was added by [CWG issue 1579](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579), expressly to require the converting move constructor `A::A(B&&)` to be called here. This is implemented in GCC 5 and Clang 3.9.

Back in 2011, this "try rvalue first" rule was closely tied to the criteria for copy elision (quoting N3337):

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be
>   met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter,
>   and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload
>   resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed
>   as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

Since copy elision necessarily requires the two to have the same type, this paragraph didn't apply, and the compiler had to use the `A::A(B&)` constructor.

Note that as CWG 1579 is considered a DR against C++11, compilers should implement its resolution even in C++11 mode.

Comment: why I got A(B&); and A(A&&) ?  I compiled the code using -fno-elide-constructors which disable RVO. 1) Isn't it meet the criteria for elision? 2) where does A(A&&) come from? Thanks in advance

Comment: @camino 1) Probably compiler version issues - the `B&&` part is implemented only in GCC trunk. 2) Returning is copy-initialization, so behaves like `A a = b;` - the `B` is first converted to a temporary `A`, and that temporary is moved into the return value.

Comment: @Mikhail My use of 2011/2014 rather than C++11/C++14 is intentional. The change was made via a defect report against C++11; such changes are usually considered "de facto" C++11 by compiler writers.