# C++11 move when returning a lock

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvo

In the book "C++ Concurrency in Action" reading the following method

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wait_for_data()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
    data_cond.wait(head_lock,[&]{return head.get()!=get_tail();});
    return std::move(head_lock);
 }
```

I cannot understand why the head_lock is std::move-ed when returned. My notion and gut feeling of the move usage and RVO matches the opinion shared in [C++11 rvalues and move semantics confusion (return statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement)

But I kind of tend to trust the author to know better. Can someone clarify when std::move the return value is better and is there something specifically about the locks? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's fine with or without the `std::move`. The name of a local variable<sup>*</sup> is treated as an rvalue in the `return` statement, causing the move constructor to be invoked in both cases. The authors presumably used `std::move` for stylistic reasons, to make it clear that the lock is being moved. It does interfere with NRVO, but the cost of moving a `unique_lock` here is probably minimal compared to the cost of the lock and the wait.

In @Deduplicator's words, it's "a pessimization in order to emphasize the actual semantics".

You can test this yourself - `unique_lock` can't be copied, so `return head_lock;` wouldn't have compiled if it were a copy.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> This is the C++14 rule. The C++11 rule is [restricted to cases where copy elision is allowed or would be allowed except for the fact that the variable is a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875596/can-returning-a-local-variable-by-value-in-c11-14-result-in-the-return-value-b/25876175#25876175). This difference is immaterial as far as this question is concerned, since `head_lock` obviously qualifies for copy elision.</sub>

Comment: I tried to compile it without move, and g++ actually compiles it.

Comment: @typical Exactly, because it is a move, not a copy, even without the `std::move`.

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini Kindly read what I wrote before shouting.

Comment: ok perfect, misunderstood the answer, you mean that by denying the copy operator, it is moved automatically ?

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini it's not a race, nicely explain your doubts and please humbly take part to the discussion. T.C. isn't forced to answer these questions.

Comment: @typical It's the subjunctive, isn't it? ;)

Comment: In conclusion, a pessimization in order to emphasize the actual semantics.