# proper use of std move for a factory class

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I want to create a factory class like below, but I am not confident this is the right way to use std::move. I don't want to use too many shared_ptrs, since shared_ptr inside another shared_ptr is really ugly and sometimes confusing...

Option 1:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
  Foo(Foo&& f){...}
}

class FooFactory
{
   public:
     static Foo&& createFoo(...)
     {
       Foo temp(...);
       return std::move(temp);
     }
}

main()
{
   Foo f=FooFactory::createFoo(...);
}
```

Option 2:

```
class FooFactory
{
   public:
     static Foo createFoo(...)
     {
       Foo temp(...);
       return temp;
     }// rely on compiler for optimization
}

main()
{
   Foo f=std::move(FooFactory::createFoo(...));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to do this is option 3 (aka *same as before*):

```
class FooFactory
{
   public:
     static Foo createFoo(...)
     {
       Foo temp(...);
       return temp;
     }
};

int main()
{
   Foo f=FooFactory::createFoo(...);
}
```

[`temp` is already treated as an rvalue in `return temp;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875596/can-returning-a-local-variable-by-value-in-c11-14-result-in-the-return-value-b/25876175#25876175). No `std::move` is necessary; similarly `FooFactory::createFoo(...);` is already an rvalue, so you don't need `std::move` either. In fact, in either case, using `std::move` is a pessimization because it inhibits move elision.

Your option 1 is not only inefficient but incorrect, as it returns a dangling reference to `temp`.