# What do I Need to Return an Object with a unique_ptr Member?

Tags: c++, return, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, virtual-destructor

Let's say that I have this object:

```
struct foo {
    std::unique_ptr<int> mem;
    virtual ~foo() = default;
};
```

I can no longer return a `foo` object created in a function:

```
foo make_foo() {
    foo result;

    result.mem = std::make_unique<int>({});
    return result;
}
```

As may be indicated I need the destructor to be virtual because this will be a base class. But even if I'm using the default destructor, that's not enough, I still can't return an object created in a function.

I get the error:

```
error C2280: foo::foo(const foo &): attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Is there a way to navigate around this issue?

Comment: Try adding `foo() = default;`, `foo(foo &&) = default;` and `foo &operator=(foo &&) = default;`. Move constructor will not be generated implicitly if you have defined move assignment operator copy constructor/assignment operator or destructor.

Comment: @user463035818 The very last error message is */usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:359:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;*

Comment: @NathanOliver oh right, I am too much used to fix first things first so i overlooked it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [[class.copy.ctor]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#8)

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if [...]
>
> - X does not have a user-declared destructor.

Since

```
virtual ~foo() = default;
```

is a user-declared destructor you no longer have a move constructor so it tries to use the copy constructor but can't because that is deleted as you have a non-copyable member.

To get the move constructor back, and to keep the default constructable, you need to add

```
foo() = default;
foo(foo&&) = default;
foo &operator=(foo &&) = default; // add this if you want to move assign as well
```

to `foo`

---

The reason you have to add `foo() = default;` when you add `foo(foo&&) = default;` is that `foo(foo&&) = default;` is a used-declared constructor and if you have any user-declared constructors then the default constructor is no longer provided.

---

This is a "hack" but what you could do is move the virtual destructor into another class and then inherit from that.  That will give you a virtual destructor in `foo` without having to declare it and give you the default constructors you want.  That would look like

```
struct make_virtual
{
    virtual ~make_virtual() = default;
};

struct foo : make_virtual {
    std::unique_ptr<int> mem;
};
```

Comment: I do keep forgetting that defaulting a destructor is *not* the same as the default destructor. There's no other way to make the default destructor virtual is there?

Comment: @JonathanMee No.  C++ really makes you pay for it the first time (the base class).  In the derived classes `~derived()` will be implicitly virtual.

Comment: @JonathanMee Actually I have just added a "hack" for you.

Comment: Just another note here, in my C++14 compiler, defaulting the move constructor only solves the error if I change the `return` statement of `make_foo` to: `return move(result)` I would have thought that should have worked automatically? Should I have to be doing this `move`?

Comment: @JonathanMee What compiler and version are you using?  [Per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875596/can-returning-a-local-variable-by-value-in-c11-14-result-in-the-return-value-b) `result` should be treated as an rvalue since it is a local automatic object.

Comment: Curses nope, it's just cause my locally constructed variable was a `foo&&` once I fixed that it moved properly.

Comment: @JonathanMee Does this answer everything for you then?

Comment: Yup you got it all. Thank you so much. I'll accept after letting it mellow for a bit...

Answer (score 1):

Either provide your own copy constructor and a default constructor, convert the member to a shared pointer or provide a move constructor. One possible solution:

```
struct foo {
    unique_ptr<int> mem;
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo& copy);
    virtual ~foo() = default;
};

foo::foo(const foo& copy) : mem(new int(*copy.mem)) {}

foo make_foo() {
    foo result;
    result.mem = make_unique<int>();
    return result;
}
```