# Do I need to use std::move again?

Tags: c++11, rvalue

For below code, I want to use the std::move to improve the efficiency. I have two functions, the first function uses std::move, and the second function just calls the first function. So, do I need to use std::move again in the function "vector convertToString()"? Why and why not? Thank you.

```
class Entity_PortBreakMeasure
{
public:
Entity_PortBreakMeasure(){}
int portfolioId;
string portfolioName;
int businessDate;
string assetType;
string currency;
string country;
string industry;
string indicator;
double value;

inline double operator()()
{
    return value;
}

static vector<string> convertToString(Entity_PortBreakMeasure& pbm)
{

    //PORTFOLIOID   INDUSTRY    CURRENCY    COUNTRY BUSINESSDATE    ASSETTYPE   INDICATOR VALUE PORTFOLIONAME
    vector<string> result;

    result.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<string>(pbm.portfolioId));
    result.push_back(pbm.industry);
    result.push_back(pbm.currency);
    result.push_back(pbm.country);
    result.push_back(Date(pbm.businessDate).ToString());
    result.push_back(pbm.assetType);
    result.push_back(pbm.indicator);
    result.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<string>(pbm.value));
    result.push_back(pbm.portfolioName);

    return std::move(result);
}

vector<string> convertToString()
{
    return convertToString(*this);
}
```

Comment: The first function should just say `return result;`. This has been discussed many times, [e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17473753/596781).

Answer (score 0):

`move()` shouldn't be used for either of these functions.

In the first function, you're returning a local variable.  Without `move()`, most (all?) compilers will perform NRVO and you won't get a copy or a move -- the returned variable will be constructed directly in the returned value for the caller.  Even if the compiler is, for some reason, unable to do NRVO, local variables become r-values when used as the argument to a `return`, so you'll get a move anyway.  Using `move()` here serves only to inhibit NRVO and *force* the compiler to do a move (or a copy in the event that the move isn't viable).

In the second function, you're returning an r-value already, since the first function returns by value.  `move()` here doesn't add anything but complexity (which might possibly confuse an optimizer into producing suboptimal code or failing to do copy elision).