# Return by reference in C++ - Reference assignment vs value assignment

Tags: c++

Suppose I have:

```
    class SomeObject {

    };

    SomeObject& f() {
        SomeObject *s = new SomeObject();
        return *s;
    }

    // Variant 1
    int main() {
        SomeObject& s = f();
        // Do something with s
    }

   // Variant 2
    int main() {
        SomeObject s = f();
        // Do something with s
    }
```

Is there any difference between the first variant and the second? any cases I would use one over the other?

Edit: One more question, what does `s` contain in both cases?

Comment: In the first case, you atleast have a chance to cleanup, in the second case, you're leaking memory...

Comment: With the way `f` is defined, the second is a memory leak.

Comment: Just plain wrong. It's very counter-intuitive having to receive something by reference where the intent is for me to own the value. More distressing is the need to do something like `delete &s;` afterwards...

Comment: @Nim I'm more interested with what is s in both cases? meaning, what happens when you return by reference to a variable not declared as a reference

Comment: @Shmoopy, define a copy c'tor that prints and see for yourself.

Comment: Alternatives to returning a reference to a heap allocated object: construct on the stack and "move" the object with std::move; return a std::unique_ptr to the heap allocated object.

Comment: @MarkGarcia Yes.  The almost universal convention is that return by reference doesn't transfer any ownership, but is used to allow modification of an object owned by the "function" (which is almost always a member function, or somehow associated with data for which it is responsible).

Comment: @A.B, it should be constructed on the stack, but it should not be `move`d.  Return values in C++11 are implicitly `move`d on your behalf.  See  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move](this question on the matter).

Comment: @Shmoopy, you should probably return by value `SomeObject`.  And no, it won't be as slow as you might think it is!  It may be faster than returning a pointer, as `new` can be quite slow sometimes.  Or a pointer `SomeObject*`, to make clear that the caller has to take ownership of the object.  Or better still, use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.  (Are you allowed to use C++11 ? ).  Return by reference only in the situation @JamesKanze is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first variant you attach a reference directly to a dynamically allocated object. This is a rather unorthodox way to own dynamic memory (a pointer would be better suited for that purpose), but still it gives you the opportunity to properly deallocate that object. I.e. at the end of your first `main` you can do

```
delete &s;
```

In the second variant you lose the reference, i.e. you lose the only link to that dynamically allocated object. The object becomes a memory leak.

Again, owning a dynamically allocated object through a reference does not strike me as a good practice. It is usually better to use a pointer or a smart pointer for that purpose. For that reason, both of your variants are flawed, even though the first one is formally redeemable.

Answer (score 2):

First, you never want to return a reference to an object which
was dynamically allocated in the function.  This is a memory
leak waiting to happen.

Beyond that, it depends on the semantics of the object, and what
you are doing.  Using the reference (variant 1) allows
modification of the object it refers to, so that some other
function will see the modified value.  Declaring a value
(variant 2) means that you have your own local copy, and any
modifications, etc. will be to it, and not to the object
referred to in the function return.

Typically, if a function returns a reference to a non-const,
it's because it expects the value to be modified; a typical
example would be something like `std::vector<>::operator[]`,
where an expression like:

```
v[i] = 42;
```

is expected to modify the element in the vector.  If this is
*not* the case, then the function should return a value, not
a reference (and you should almost never use such a function to
initialize a local reference).  And of course, this only makes
sense if you return a reference to something that is accessible
elsewhere; either a global variable or (far more likely) data
owned by the class of which the function is a member.

Answer (score 0):

Variant 1 will copy the address of the object and will be fast

Variant 2 will copy the whole object and will be slow (as already pointed out in Variant2 you cant delete the object which you created by calling new)

for the edit: Both f contain the same Object

Comment: No, one is a copy of an object, the other is a reference to an object. Those don't "contain the same object".

Comment: First, of course: the semantics of the two variants are _not_ the same: in the first case, modifications to the object through the initialized variable will modify the original object; in the second, only the local copy.  And second, even in the second case, the copy may or may not take place.  Most of the time, most compilers will optimize it out.

Answer (score 0):

None of the two options you asked about is very good. In this particular case you should use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, or `auto_ptr` if you use older C++ compilers, and change the function so it returns pointer, not reference. Another good option is returning the object by value, especially if the object is small and cheap to construct.

Modification to return the object by value:

```
SomeObject f() { return SomeObject(); }

SomeObject s(f());
```

Simple, clean, safe - no memory leaking here.

Using `unique_ptr`:

```
SomeObject* f() { return new SomeObject(); }

unique_ptr<SomeObject> s(f());
```

One of the advantages of using a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` here is that you can change your function `f` at some point to return objects of a class derived from `SomeObject` and none of your client code will need to be changed - just make sure the base class (`SomeObject`) has a virtual constructor.

Why the options you were considering are not very good:

Variant 1:

```
SomeObject& s = f();
```

How are you going to destroy the object? You will need address of the object to call it's destructor anyway, so at some point you would need to dereference the object that `s` refers to (`&s`)

Variant 2. You have a leak here and not a chance to call destructor of the object returned from your function.

Comment: Are you sure that a smart pointer is indicated here?  To me, it looks more like the function shouldn't return a reference, but a value, and that no dynamic allocation should be involved.

Comment: Well, whether the function should return a value or a pointer depends on the class of the object returned: if this is something small, simple and cheap to copy than by value is preferred. But sometimes you cannot afford to copy objects unnecessarily .

Comment: @JamesKanze But it's a good point, I will add the option to my answer.

Comment: Whether a function should return a value or a pointer depends on the semantics involved.  If the profiler shows that the copying is a problem, then you might have to revise, but generally, compilers are very good at optimizing out unnecessary copies (and if you have C++11, adding move semantics to the object may allow you to keep the appearance of value semantics anyway---again, not something to do prematurely, but if the optimizer says you must, it's a very nice option to have available).

Comment: Ok, I agree. But there is another reason why returning a pointer may be be advantageous: polymorphism. I have updated my answer.