# C++11 move semantics and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following code:

```
class StringTokenizer 
{
private:
    char m_delimiter;
    std::istringstream m_string;

public:
    explicit StringTokenizer(const std::string& str, char delimiter)
    : m_string(str)
    , m_delimiter(delimiter)
    {
    }

    template <class Container>
    operator Container ()
    {
        Container container;
        for (std::string token; std::getline(m_string, token, m_delimiter); )
        {
            container.insert(container.end(), token);
        }
        return container;
    }
};
```

This is the usage:

```
vector<string> tmp = StringTokenizer("123 456", ' '); //Please note the implicit conversion
```

When debugging the following happens (Using VS2013):

At the `return` statement of conversion operator

1. new vector constructed from `container` by moving
2. `container` gets destructed

After function return:

1. `tmp` is constructed by copy constructor

My question is why isn't `tmp` constructed by move constructor ?

As I understand things function return type is rvalue and should be moved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++11 Return value optimization or move?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move)

Comment: Hmm g++ and clang++ (libstdc++ and libc++) *do* move the `vector`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27aacf34fc3e22b3 while VS2013 copies it: http://rextester.com/JEXDDD72242

Comment: VS2013 also moves the vector when calling the conversion operator explicitly: http://rextester.com/SSMH48781

Comment: VS2015 also moves. Just a bug, I suppose.

Comment: @dyp When the conversion is implicit VS2013 copy rather than moving

Comment: @AlejandroFreeman I know, I just don't understand it. T.C.'s probably right, this looks like a bug.

Comment: shouldn't this do a NRVO?

Answer (score 2):

VS2013 doesn't automatically generate the move constructor/assignment. This is solved in later versions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#rvref