# Object gets constructed from return value without copy or move constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, constructor, intellisense, move

I've got an `Action` class that looks like this (in its stripped down form):

```
struct Action {

explicit Action(...some parameters...); // I only use this to construct Action objects

Action(const Action&) = delete; // Don't want copy constructor
Action(Action&&) = delete; // Same for move constructor

}
```

In some other translation unit, I have tried to do this:

```
Action action = someMethodForGettingActions(); // The method returns Action objects by rvalue
```

Visual Studio's Intellisense wants to hang me for this, justifiably. It says it can't access the move constructor.
Yet this **compiles and runs as expected**. What's going on here? Is this some compiler optimization playing mind tricks on me?

Comment: Which intellisense parser specifically? Not all the IDE's use the same.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: This takes advantage of return value optimisation, but the compiler should forbid compilation because you have deleted the `const Action&` constructor, even though it doesn't actually need to use it.

Comment: @Dave It does though. And it's driving me nuts. Try it yourself.

Comment: It doesn't in GCC. This is almost certainly a Visual Studio compiler bug: https://ideone.com/wePDoN

Comment: https://ideone.com/rDEcyK I have modified it a bit to fit my case, but it doesn't compile either. Definitely a VS quirk.

Comment: [MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1010149/c-unrvo-optimization-causes-delete-function-qualifier-to-be-ignored-allowing-invalid-c-code-to-compile-and-run). Your example in the comment above fails to compile on VS2015. Test it [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

Comment: @Praetorian I would mark this as the accepted question if I could. This settles it then.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) at work.
It is actually permitted by C++11 standard. Check the accepted answer of:

[c++11 Return value optimization or move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move)

The question there was a bit different, but the answer fits your problem.

Comment: So the compiler just blatantly lets you compile wrong code because it knows it will be optimized out? Is RVO really this taken for granted nowadays?

Comment: The compiler is still supposed to reject compilation of such code if the copy & move constructor is explicitly forbidden. The fact that they are not actually used is irrelevant. Try the compiling the same code with GCC.

Comment: @Dave It appears (based on the specification quoted in that link) that an implementation is both allowed to accept the code, and allowed to reject it if it does not want to perform copy elision for whatever reason (note "is allowed to omit").

Comment: @JohnColanduoni elision rules apply only *after* the validity of the program is established. See for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision "Even when copy elision takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed."