# Which one -- default or copy constructor -- of a class gets called when I define a function that has (non-reference) return type of that class?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I was puzzled as why I had to write copy constructor of this one class when I defined a function inside another class with the return type of the first mentioned class.

For example:

```
class Foo{
    // attributes
public:
    Foo(){...}

    // I had to write the CC
    Foo(const Foo& obj){
        //...
    }
}

class Bar{
// ....

// This is the function
Foo SomeFunction()
{
    Foo myVar;

    // ....

    return myVar;
}
```

I checked by `cout`ing that the copy constructor is actually being called.

I need confirmation though because it would seem more logical to me that the default constructor is called in this situation, like in this line where `myVar` is created.

I'm a beginner so I'm trying to wrap my head around these calls.

Comment: `myVar` is a local variable inside the function, it needs to be copied to the outside variable.

Comment: @songyuanyao So the copy constructor is invoked when that copying occurs?

Comment: Yes, via copy ctor or copy assignment.

Comment: Another duplicate: [c++11 Return value optimization or move?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move)

Comment: don't really think this is a duplicate, OP is asking why there is a copy operation in his code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
Foo myFunc;
```

calls the default constructor.

The line

```
return myFunc;
```

calls the copy constructor since the return type of the function is `Foo`. The object returned from the function is not `myFunc` but a copy of `myFunc`. `myFunc` gets deleted when the function returns. The copy is what the calling function gets.

If the compiler is able to use RVO ([return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)), then `myFunc` is returned to the calling function, not a copy. In that case, the copy constructor will not get called.

Comment: actually, depending on the optimization capabilities of the compiler, the return statement may actually call the move constructor as well if NRVO is applied.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, good point in general. For this specific case, the implicitly declared move constructor is deleted since the OP has a copy constructor, at least that's my understanding.

Comment: Yes, I'm not trying to nitpick, just added this since OP might be interested in knowing that in case s/he encounters a movable type in the future.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant ITYM that if NRVO is *not* applied then this calls the move constructor if present .  (If NRVO applies then no constructor happens)

Comment: @RSahu There is no implicitly generated move constructor (if OP didn't declare one that he's hiding of course).

Comment: @M.M, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor seems to indicate that the compiler will generate a move constructor if certain conditions are met.

Comment: @RSahu one of the conditions is "there are no user-declared copy constructors;", but OP declared a copy-constructor

Comment: @M.M, we are on the same page on this.

Comment: @RSahu you said "the implicitly declared move constructor is deleted", which is false.  There is no implicitly declared move constructor.  "No function" is different to "Deleted function".

Comment: @M.M, I see your point. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @M.M Yes, you are right, I meant that.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to write a CC on C++. The compiler should give you one. 
And yes, a CC will be invoked in this case since you are trying to pass the return value as a copy.

Comment: The default cc wouldn't work in this particular situation because I had to have some pointers initialised.

Comment: You shouldn't downvote this because you have not shown the complete  implementation of the class and what I said holds completely true. If your class had attributes which don't have CC defined on them, that's the reason you would need to specify one while using one.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted your answer.