# Why is the move constructor being called?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, rvo

Given my understanding of return value optimization, I am a confused as to why the move constructor is being called in the sample code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyCustomType
{
public:
  MyCustomType()
  {
    std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  MyCustomType(const MyCustomType & inOther) : // copy constructor
    mData(inOther.mData)
  {
    std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  MyCustomType(MyCustomType && inOther) : // move constructor
    mData(std::move(inOther.mData))
  {
    std::cout << "Move constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::vector<int> mData;
};

MyCustomType getCustomType()
{
  MyCustomType _customType;
  return _customType;
}

int main()
{
  MyCustomType _t = getCustomType();
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor called
Move constructor called
```

I assumed that there would only be a single instance of MyCustomType constructed and assigned directly to `_t`.

For info, I am using the VC14 compiler.

Comment: Why did you assume that? Because of the C++ rules (which you would have misunderstood) or because of optimisations (which can be a bit unpredictable)?

Comment: @BoBTFish Both, I assumed the C++ standard permitted single-construction in such a case and hoped the compiler would be smart enough to notice it.

Comment: If you only wanted a single instance constructed without any other constructor calls it would be `MyCustomType _t();` but in your post first a temporary instance is created `getCustomType()` and the assignment operator does not initiate a copy construction but a move construction. Which saves resources. C++ does not simplify your code that far, that it would convert those two statements.

Comment: See also,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move . And if you compile in release mode, MSVC will likely eliminate the move as well. Note also that the move constructor normally should take a non-const argument

Comment: @Aeonos: You meant `MyCustomType _t{};` (as you have vexing parse: function declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you assume that NRVO will be applied. But NRVO is just an *optimization*, which is not guaranteed to be used by the compiler ^.

I have tested your example with http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

The default set of compiler options there is:

```
/EHsc /nologo /W4
```

In such case the output is similar with yours:

```
Constructor called

Move constructor called
```

But if appropriate optimization is enabled with, say, `/O2` flag:

```
/O2 /EHsc /nologo /W4
```

Then the output is:

```
Constructor called
```

^ As @einpoklum has mentioned in the comments, rules have changed since C++17.

Comment: Actually, in C++17 I think copy elision for return values will be [guaranteed](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/guaranteed-copy-elision/#guaranteedcopyelision) under reasonable conditions.

Comment: @einpoklum Good remark! Anyway, OP uses VC14 compiler :)

Comment: @einpoklum It's only guaranteed when returning a prvalue; at least not for the OP's case.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Fair enough, but this answer says that NRVO is just an optimization, so I had to qualify that.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes. It might be more precise that the NRVO for OP's case is just an optimization.

Comment: @einpoklum: prvalues are never *named*. Therefore, guaranteed elision never applies to named RVO.

Answer (score 1):

Because expression `getCustomType()` is a [prvalue(rvalue)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), and parameter can be more cv-qualified than argument.

In order to see "more" copy elision, you can try release compiling mode.

BTW, `inOther.mData` isn't moved, `mData(std::move(inOther.mData))` will in fact call vector's copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks, modified the move constructor to be non-const.