# Why does compiler use move constructor instead of the copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it ok that the following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo" << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo" << std::endl; }

    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(const Foo&)" << std::endl; }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) { std::cout << "Foo::operator=(const Foo&)" << std::endl; return *this; }

    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(Foo&&)" << std::endl; }
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) { std::cout << "Foo::operator=(Foo&&)" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

Foo foo()
{
    Foo second;
    return second;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

produces such output:

```
Foo::Foo
Foo::Foo(Foo&&)
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
```

Why does it call move constructor instead of the copy constructor?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17473753/335858)

Comment: which compiler do you use and what are compiler arguments?

Comment: @Dev Null MSVC-14.0

Comment: I suspect that optimisation is turned off in your settings when you compile because I would expect move constructor and one of destructor calls to be optimised away due to RVO.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simply because the standard says so. Section 12.8, paragraph 32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an exception-declaration, and the
>   object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, or when the expression in a return statement is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, overload resolution
>   to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

And that's basically all there is to it. Logically, if the variable has automatic storage duration, and you `return` it, then immediately after the return, the variable will not exist any more when the local scope cleans up. That is why, even though it is an lvalue, it is quite similar to an rvalue. Because it's still technically an lvalue, this exception has to be made explicitly in the standard, and here we are. Note that this whole situation is specific to `return`ing from a function, and does not include scope ending in general.

Comment: The standard also says the return is a candidate for copy elision. It is *very* strange that RVO doesn't take place here.

Answer (score 2):

`second` is returned from `foo`, and, being a local object, is treated as an rvalue (thanks to Nir Friedman for the correct [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45626508/8414561)). The returned `Foo` object is constructed from a temporary, which binds to the move constructor.

Modern compiler should skip the move constructor call and use [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ea94b21cfd0678)).

Comment: Why does it created from a temporary? I thought that the `second` is an l-value here

Comment: because `second` goes out of scope and can't be assigned (i.e. be at the left side of `=`) anymore.

Comment: But it is still in the scope during the `return` statement, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but *after* return it's no longer in scope, a `Foo` object in scope of `main` is created from a temporary object that is no longer in scope as `foo` has finished.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks

Comment: This answer is incorrect, insofar as just because a variable is going out of scope does not mean that it will be treated as an rvalue.