# incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: c++, c++11

I was hoping the return values in c++11 are already moved or optimized out as explained in here: [c++11 Return value optimization or move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move)

However I am having this exception below.  
 *"inference(4160,0x7fffb832e380) malloc:*  error for object 0x7fc415f00a10: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
 *set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"*. 

The code:

```
vector<double> sp_peaks = dsp.diff(zero_sp_cropped);
sp_peaks = dsp.sign(sp_peaks);
sp_peaks = dsp.diff(sp_peaks);
```

The third line is giving the error.

 The sign and diff methods are below.

```
vector<double> SignalProcessing::diff(vector<double> &signal) {
    /*
     * Performs the diff filter on the input signal and returns the value.
     * The returned signal has length 1 less than the input signal.
     * */

    vector<double> res(signal.size()-1); // -1 because the first one cannot have a diff

    for (int i = 1; i < signal.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = signal[i]-signal[i-1];
    }
    return res;
}

vector<double> SignalProcessing::sign(vector<double> &signal) {
    /*
     * Maps the input signal into a signal of {-1.0,1.0} values by their sign values.
     * Positive values will be mapped to 1.0 while negative will be mapped to -1.0
     * */
    vector<double> res(signal.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < signal.size(); ++i) {
        if (signal[i] > 0)
            res[i] = 1.0;
        else
            res[i] = -1.0;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The error disappears if I place a breakpoint and debug. Could you explain why this is happening and what is a good practice of returning an std container? 
Thank you in advance! 
Anil

Comment: Off by one error.  The size of the vector is `res(signal.size()-1)` but you loop till `i < signal.size()`, not `i < signal.size() - 1`

Comment: No, that part is correct. I start i from one. That was intentional.

Comment: then you need `res[i-1] = signal[i]-signal[i-1];` because say signal is size=2 then res has 1 element -- BUT it's at index 0, but you try to put it into index 1

Comment: But you do `res[i]` in the loop and `res[i]` does not exist when `i == signal.size() - 1`

Comment: One of the first things you can do when trying to debug code like this is add `assert`s before every array access to catch any attempt at an out of bounds access. That would have found this problem easily. Or you could even have just used [at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) which exists for this purpose.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz or turn on your STL's debug macros.. or just use `.at` instead of `[]`

Comment: You are right, that is indeed an error!

Comment: Alright, the exception is gone. It was due to what @NathanOliver pointed out. Thanks Nathan!

Comment: I believe this is the 3rd off by one array access bug today. Should these be answered or is there a good duplicate or should they be closed as a typo?

Comment: Off by one exists in murk-space. Be hard to make a generic answer to use as a landing pad without it being overly broad (and in my opinion useless) like the generic Unresolved External Q&A. The big take-away is every time you THINK you are correctly using one-based indexing, you probably aren't.