# Is there a way return and delete content of an std::string?

Tags: c++, sockets, stdstring

I am writing a socket server in C++ and need to wrapper the read function, from an `std::string` buffer. As you can see in the below code for reading a single byte (`ClientConnection.readByte`), it uses a `char` to store the value, delete it, then return the `char`. However I also want to implement a readEverything (`ClientConnection.readEverything`) function, which should return the entire buffer.
Right now, I just copy the buffer, but this doesn't seem memory efficient. This would be easy if I could `return` *before* `readBuffer.erase()`, but that can't work. Is there an efficient workaround, or do I just have to use my original method?

```cpp
class ClientConnection{
private:
    int connfd;
    std::string writeBuffer;
    std::string readBuffer;
    struct sockaddr *address;
public:
    ClientConnection(int fd){
        connfd = fd;
    }
    bool available(){
        char toReturn;
        recv(connfd, &toReturn, 1, MSG_PEEK);
        return toReturn!=-1;
    }
    char readByte(){
        char thingy = readBuffer[0];
        readBuffer.erase(0, 1);
        return thingy;
    }
    std::string readEverything(){
        std::string readBufferCopy = readBuffer;
        readBuffer.erase();
        return readBufferCopy;
    }
    void writeByte(char byte){
        writeBuffer += byte;
    }
    void polleverything(){
        write(connfd, writeBuffer.c_str(), writeBuffer.length());
        char readBuffer[READOUTBUFFERSIZE];
        while (recv(connfd, &toReturn, READOUTBUFFERSIZE, 0) == READOUTBUFFERSIZE){
            std::cout << "HELLO";
        };
    }
};
```

The `ClientConnection` class is supposed to be passed file descriptors and otherwise used by a server class, which for the sake of easy-reading I omitted from this snippet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have some guarantee that the buffer won't be overwritten by the time the user uses its data? Are you confident that every part of the program would get that right? Copying seems much safer and much less complex.

Comment: You might be able to do `std::string readBufferCopy = std::move(readBuffer);` and then hope that your compiler cooperates and does NVRO.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, That part's okay since no NRVO means it's still moved out if using a standard from within the last decade (same requirement as moving the data out of the buffer in the first place).

Comment: But without NVRO a copy is still made. Granted, it's now one copy instead of two, so that's definitely progress, but without guaranteed copy elision you must still have to do a copy.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Where? It'd be moving data out of the buffer to the local variable and then moving data out of the local variable into the return value.

Comment: The return itself is NVRO, which is not guaranteed, and thus can involve a copy.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, The alternative to NRVO here [is a move, not a copy](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3). This is the reason for [the common advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move) not to `return std::move(local);`—either it would've been NRVOd but now can't be, or it would have been moved anyway and the call is redundant. All that is to say that if the poster is using C++11 or later, your comment is pretty ideal.