# Why can't I read from a reference on stream returned by function?

Tags: c++, reference, ifstream

I want to get data from a stream that my function returned, but it throws an exception when I try to. Here is my code in short form:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;
ifstream& detect() {
    ifstream stream;
    stream.open("in.txt");
    return stream;
}
int main() {
    int s;
    ifstream& fin = detect();
    fin >> s; //exception thrown: Access violation reading
    cout << s;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Is it caused because of the reference type of the "fin"?

Comment: `stream` is a local variable, so the reference to it is dangling when you return. Using the stream at that point is UB.

Comment: [If you ask politely](https://godbolt.org/z/nccn8GrPn) the compiler can warn you  about trivial mistakes like this.

Comment: @fabian Using `std::move()` like that will prevent RVO/copy elision from happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/

Answer (score 1):

`stream` in `detect()` function is a local variable and will be freed after the function call. You cannot pass a dangling reference of `stream`. Instead change the code to this:

```
ifstream detect() {
    ifstream stream;
    stream.open("in.txt");
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: `ifstream& fin = detect();` should also be changed.