# build issue on Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently having a build issue in one on my class. the dev is done in Qt/c++

header.h

```
class Ui_DialogBoxProgress : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Ui_DialogBoxProgress(QWidget *parent = 0, Cache& cache);
    ~Ui_DialogBoxProgress();
    Cache& m_cache;
```

src.cpp

```
Ui_DialogBoxProgress::Ui_DialogBoxProgress(QWidget *parent, Cache& cache) :
    QDialog(parent),
    m_cache(cache),
    ui(new Ui::Ui_DialogBoxProgress)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ...
```

Currently the error is :

```
header.h:21: error: missing default argument on parameter 'cache'
    explicit Ui_DialogBoxProgress(QWidget *parent = 0, Cache& cache);
```

and the call is done in the main.cpp like below :

```
DeleteProgress = new Ui_DialogBoxProgress(*this, *cache);
                                                          ^
```

Cache is a class defined below:

```
class Cache
{
public:
    Cache();
..
```

Any idea ? I already use this kind of method but the build never complain

Answer (score 1):

Once you define a default value for a function argument, every argument thereafter needs a default argument as well.  This is a C++ rule, not just Qt.  This will actually be difficult in your case because you're taking the second argument by non-const reference.  Can you switch the order of function arguments, or will that require refactoring a lot of code?  You can also take a `Cache` by pointer instead of reference; then you can set a default argument of `nullptr` for that argument.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c) has a decent solution that you might want to take a look at.

Comment: cache is a class defined :

Comment: thanks Carlton, it works, just neet to switch the order. I wasn't thinking that order may impact