# boost::optional vector pass by reference as default parameter

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

```
boost::optional<std::vector<std::wstring>> filePath;
```

If I have the above boost optional vector is it possible to then pass this by reference and as an optional parameter?

```
Test(const boost::filesystem::path& targetPath, boost::optional<std::vector<std::wstring>> filePath = boost::none);
```

Could I pass `filePath` as a default parameter and by reference at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default value to a parameter while passing by reference in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: There were compilation issues when i tried to do this with boost::optional @BartoszKP

Comment: Please post these errors and a minimal source code that reproduces the problem. How can we guess what you did and what happened?

Comment: This is a valid question IMO. With an interesting answer. Hold on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an optional reference:

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/optional_references.html

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f2eeff794ba44d7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void Test(const boost::filesystem::path& targetPath,
          boost::optional<std::vector<std::wstring>& > filePath = boost::none) {
    if (filePath)
        std::cout << filePath->size() << " elements\n";
    else
        std::cout << "default parameter\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::wstring> path(3, L"bla");

    Test("blabla", path);
    Test("blabla");
}
```

Prints

```
3 elements
default parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is legal, but you can't pass a reference as a default parameter. Should you want that, you'd need to pass a value, or the file path wrapped around another boost::optional.

Comment: But you can because `boost::optional` explicitly supports that

Comment: oh wow, I didn't know it supported it. you always learn something new

Answer (score 0):

Either put the reference inside the boost optional (`boost::optional<std::vector<std::wstring>& >`) as @sehe wrote, or use a **const** reference:

```
void Test(const boost::filesystem::path& targetPath,
          const boost::optional<std::vector<std::wstring> >& filePath = boost::none)
{

}
```

live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/324e31e1854fadb9

In C++ you are not allowed to [bind a temporary to  a non-const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). In this case, the default value is the temporary so you need a const reference.

Comment: This might work depending on the requirements of the OP. If the vector needs to be non-const he's out of luck. If he uses the `optional<T&> const&` then toplevel const doesn't add anything (because `optional<T&>` is just fine). You might want to add an explanation why `const&` works.

Comment: So you explain how you can bind a const-reference to a temporary by... saying you can not do something else. Mmm