# Does default-initializing a non-const reference function parameter from a dynamically allocated dereferenced pointer create a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, c++98

I'm in front of this and will have to deal with C++98, possibly C++03, and C++11 :

```
type1 myfunc( type2& var = /*some value of type "type2"*/ )
{
   // Some code
}
```

I tried this :

```
type1 myfunc( type2& var = *(new type2) )
{
   // Some code
}
```

And of course it works, but I'm not sure wether this creates or not a memory leak. What does this code **exacty do** in the computer memory ?
If I can't do this, do I have any other solutions than to overload my function?

Comment: Take const ref if you can, that'd allow you to take a temporary. If you can't, take a global variable as default param. If you can't, take an optional<> ref as input.

Comment: Make an overload, don't allocate anything. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c). Of course it's leaking.

Comment: More on const references [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784262/1460794)

Comment: Yes. It leaks memory.

Comment: Maybe rvalue reference would suit your needs? `type1 myfunc( type2&& var = type2() ) { /*... */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is tagged C++11, so I suppose you can use `std::unique_ptr` to solve this problem.

A little example

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::size_t myfunc( std::string const & var
   = * std::unique_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("default string")) )
{ return var.size(); }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << "default:  " << myfunc() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "argument: " << myfunc("no default") << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Hoping this helps.

**--- added C++98/C++03 solution ---**

Isn't clear what language the OP want to use.

In case of C++98/C++03, it's possible to use `std::auto_ptr` instead of the C++11 `std::unique_ptr`.

I remember that `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated from C++11, so use it **only** if you can't use C++11 (or a newer standard)

The following example should be C++98 compliant (I've removed the `const` too)

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::size_t myfunc(std::string & var
   = * std::auto_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("default string")) )
{ return var.size(); }

int main ()
 {
   std::string noDef("no default");

   std::cout << "default:  " << myfunc() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "argument: " << myfunc(noDef) << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - are you sure?

Comment: @NicolBolas: You sure? According to my example, this also works with non-const reference (not saying it is a particular good solution)

Comment: @max66: No, my mistake. I forgot that the initialization expression happens within the context of the calling function.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I've tryed a test similar to the one of MikeMB and, even without const, the destruction of my test class is at the end of the function.

Comment: @all - sorry for my bad English

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - more I study C++11, more I think it'a a nightmare to understand how it exactly work; thanks to help me to understand

Comment: If this could be proven to be a reliable solution without const then it would be very interesting. I'm curious to learn what the standard says about the lifetime of objects declared this way.

Comment: @flatmouse - +1: I'm curious too.

Comment: @flatmouse: I don't see the problem: The temporary unique_ptr instance lives until the end of the expression containing the call to myfunc and by extension, the same is true for the object managed by it. The question if the reference is const or not is completely irrelevant for this - either it works for both or for none.

Comment: My bad, I mistakenly added "C++11" instead of "C++0x", but thank you for your answer !

Comment: @cylgom - if I'm not wrong, "C++0x" is the old identifier for "C++11"; but, exactly, what language are you using?

Comment: @cylgom - I've modified my answer adding a solution C++98/C++03 compliant (but deprecated for C++11/C++14/...); but I renew my question: exactly, which version of the C++ standard are you using?

Comment: @max66 owwww I didn't know that. Sorry for the confusion. C++11 was ok then

Comment: @max66 I'm glad you added solutions for all versions, this is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you allocate memory and don't delete it you have a memory leak, regardless of the shenanigans you pull with dereferencing, references, or pointer manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

This code will create a memory leak in situations when the default parameter is used, unless `myfunc` frees it (which would be a hack):

```
type1 myfunc( type2& var = *(new type2) ) {
   // Some code
   delete &var; // Very bad, don't do it like that.
}
```

When the call is made with a parameter specified for the `var`, there would be no memory leak without the `delete`. This is because the compiler sees that you are passing an argument for the reference parameter, and not allocate `new type2`.

One approach to create a default reference without making a memory leak is to define a static throw-away variable, and use it as a reference:

```
static type2 throwaway;
type1 myfunc( type2& var = throwaway ) {
    // Some code
}
```

This way the callers who do not need to see modifications done to `var` would be able to call your function without specifying a reference for it. Of course if `myfunc` makes any modifications to `var`, the callers would not be able to see them.

Comment: If that first function was called with an argument, you would calling `delete` on an object that was not necessarily allocated with `new`.

Comment: Imho, you should - at least - make throwaway `thread_local` to avoid hidden dataraces.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That's right, that's precisely why I called it a hack, and added a comment.