# How to set a default value for std::list argument in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to set an empty list as a default value to the list argument. I've tried using {}, list.(), NULL, and {NULL} to no avail.

`void f(std::list<treeNode*> &path = ??);`

When `{}` is used,

```
error: could not convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>()’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::list<treeNode*>&’
```

When `list<treeNode*>()` is used,

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
 void f(treeNode* root, int &n, list<treeNode*> &path = list<treeNode*>.()){
```

Comment: You didn't have `&` in your original example. That's important to know.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate now, as it's the same for all references, not just `std::list`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void f(std::list<treeNode*> = ??);
> ```

You can use a pair of empty curly brackets:

```
void f(std::list<treeNode*> = {});
```

---

> I've tried using ... list.()

This is a syntax error.

> NULL,

A `std::list` cannot be initialised from a pointer constant.

> and {NULL}

This initialises a non-empty list with a single null element.

> {} ... to no avail.

This is the correct solution since C++11. In pre-C++11 standards, you would have had to repeat the type name:

```
void f(std::list<treeNode*> = std::list<treeNode*>())
```

---

Edit regarding the new question:

> ```
> void f(std::list<treeNode*> &path = ??);
> ```

This is different. A non-const lvalue reference cannot be bound to an initialiser list. You have to either:

1. Use a const lvalue reference argument.
2. Or use an rvalue reference argument.
3. Or initialise the non-const lvalue reference to some static object by default... Which is not a good option if the function changes the argument. If the argument is not chnaged, use 1. instead.

Comment: Strange, OP said that he used {} with no success

Comment: @Amadeus¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯ maybe they made a mistake.