# C++ different output using global variables vs passing variable thorugh function

Tags: c++, global-variables, binary-tree

I was solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/tree-top-view/problem) question.

When the `min` and `max` variables are set as global variable, I'm getting the correct output, but when I pass them in the functions it messes up the output.

I can't figure out the reason. **Can someone tell me, how are these two code snippets different.**

`global:`

```
    int min = 1,max = 0;

    //dfs in which left subtree is travelled before right
    void travLeft(Node * root, int i,vector<int> &left)
    {
        if(root==NULL) return;
        
        if(i<min)
        {
            min = i;
            left.push_back(root->data);
        }
        
        travLeft(root->left,i-1,left);
        travLeft(root->right,i+1,left);
    }
    
     void travRight(Node * root, int i,vector<int> &right)
    {
        if(root==NULL) return;
        
        if(i>max)
        {
            max = i;
            right.push_back(root->data);
        }
        
        travRight(root->right,i+1,right);
        travRight(root->left,i-1,right);
    }
    
    void topView(Node * root) {
        
        vector<int> left,right;
        
        travLeft(root,0,left);
        travRight(root,0,right);
        
        for(int i=left.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            cout<<left[i]<<" ";
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<right.size();i++)
        {
            cout<<right[i]<<" ";
        }
        
    }
```

`passing in the function :`

```
    //dfs in which left subtree is travelled before right
    void travLeft(Node * root,int min, int i,vector<int> &left)
    {
        if(root==NULL) return;
        
        if(i<min)
        {
            min = i;
            left.push_back(root->data);
        }
        
        travLeft(root->left,min,i-1,left);
        travLeft(root->right,min,i+1,left);
    }
    
     void travRight(Node * root,int max, int i,vector<int> &right)
    {
        if(root==NULL) return;
        
        if(i>max)
        {
            max = i;
            right.push_back(root->data);
        }
        
        travRight(root->right,max,i+1,right);
        travRight(root->left,max,i-1,right);
    }
    
    void topView(Node * root) {
        
        vector<int> left,right;
        
        travLeft(root,INT_MAX,0,left);
        travRight(root,0,0,right);
        
        for(int i=left.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            cout<<left[i]<<" ";
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<right.size();i++)
        {
            cout<<right[i]<<" ";
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable is global. The changes to the value will retain among all calls of `travLeft` and `travRight`.

On the other hand, the argument is local to the function. The new value of `min` and `max` are passed to the next level of recursion, but the update of `min` in the first recursion

```
travLeft(root->left,min,i-1,left);
```

will not passed to the second recursion

```
travLeft(root->right,min,i+1,left);
```

Because the same value of `min`, which is updated (or not updated and come from the previous level) at this level, is passed for the two calls.
The same thing will also happen with `max` and `travRight`.

This is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When using as global variables, the changes will take place(and retain the changes) through out all the layers. But, if you pass them to the function, for every recursion stage(layer)  the variables will have certain values, which will remain unchanged for that particular layer.

Answer (score 0):

@MikeCat and @SoumitraChatterjee has already stated the reason why your version that passes in the variable fail to work.

To make it work, you can alternatively set the parameter to take in `min` and `max` as references, so the changes will be reflexed to the original value:

```
void travLeft(Node* root, int& min, int i, vector<int> &left) { //... }
                          ^^^^
```

---

Note that it might be tempting to set a default value to parameter `max` and `min` like:

```
//                                                   this doesn't work
//                                                      ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
// void travLeft(Node* root, int i, vector<int> &left, int& min = 0)
```

However, this will not work because you are attempting to set `min` to a the reference of a temporary value, which does not work.

For more about that, consider: [Default value to a parameter while passing by reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c)