# How to pass vector of vector as default argument in functions, C++

Tags: c++, vector

IDE showing error at last argument. I am new in C++ and unable to figure it out.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
void Box_2(vector<vector<int>> &v,
           string text1 = "", 
           string text2 = "",  
           vector<vector<int>> &trace = {}
)
```

Comment: Are you supposed to modify the vector `trace`? If not, then pass it by *constant* reference (e.g. `vector<vector<int>> const& trace = {}`)

Comment: Change the last parameter to `const vector<vector<int>> &trace = {}`.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059630/default-value-to-a-parameter-while-passing-by-reference-in-c.

Comment: Have a helper function with a shorter signature, then have that forward (thunk) to the actual function. `void Box_2(vector<vector<int>> &v, string text1 = "", string text2 = "") { vector<vector<int>> tv; Box_2(v, text1, text2, tv); }`  The full function wouldn't have any defaulted parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that we cannot bind an *lvalue reference to a non-const object* to a temporary of the corresponding type.

For instance,

```
int &ref = 5; //THIS WILL NOT WORK
const int &REF = 5; //THIS WILL WORK
```

---

To **solve** this error you can make the last parameter `name` to be an *lvalue reference to a const object* which is allowed to bound to a temporary as shown below:

```
void Box_2(vector<vector<int>> &v,
           string text1 = "", 
           string text2 ="",  
//---------vvvvv------------------------------------->low level const added here
           const vector<vector<int>> &trace = {}
);
```

Note that with above you won't be able to change `name`. This is a consequence of adding the low-level `const`.

---

You can also just leave off the default arguments altogether as shown below:

```
void Box_2(vector<vector<int>> &v, string text1, string text2, vector<vector<int>> &trace);
```

Now you will be able to change the underlying vector to which `name` is bound.

Comment: Yes, it's working, but I believe I won't be able to alter this vector.

Comment: Do you mind telling me, how to pass it in another way where I can edit it.

Comment: @gaurav Yes, that is a consequence of adding the low-level `const`. You can just leave off the default argument altogether though. Like `void Box_2(vector<vector<int>> &v, string text1, string text2, vector<vector<int>> &trace);` Now you will be able to change the orignal vector to which `name` is bound.